# Spring JDBC is not logging SQL with log4j

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, log4j

I'm researching spring for a possible switch to a spring stack.  One of the things that I thought was cool was the ability for spring jdbc to log all the executed sql.  So I put in log4j, set up a log4j.properties file.  and no sql.

here is the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppe nder
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.Patt ernLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG
```

here is the output for some really simple insert sql via spring jdbc: http://pastie.org/713189

Comment: Did you restart the server? Is Threshold set?

Comment: Hi phil ... What did u do resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 11):

Try setting these additional `log4j` loggers.  The first will spit out the SQL that passes through spring's `JdbcTemplate`, the second gives you parameter values that Spring sets on prepared statements.

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils">
  <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Clearly this is only going to work if you're directly or indirectly executing SQL using `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Second one do not give values in jdbctemplate PreparedStatementSetter

Comment: Just use this one, you should be all set: log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=TRACE

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is the `log4.properties` that your application is picking up?  I copied the `log4j.properties` you posted into a Spring application on my local machine, and I got a ton of Spring debug entries in addition to the JDBC logging.  I don't see debug entries like that in your output.

A few probable culprits for your `log4j.properties` not getting read correctly are:

- `log4j.properties` isn't on your classpath.  You can trying doing a `class.getResource()` on it to see if it's finding it at all.
- There's another `log4j.properties` on your classpath.
- Something is making commons-logging choose to use a different logger.  You can find instructions for turning on the commons-logging diagnositics [here](http://commons.apache.org/logging/troubleshooting.html#Using%20JCL%20Diagnostics)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

This helped me, `DEBUG` just wasn't enough. I am using org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar with log4j-1.2.15 and slf4j (1.6.4)

For just an SQL (i.e. if you're not interested in bound parameter values) `DEBUG` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding spring will print out information when you use prepared statement.

See [this discussion](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=52501) on Spring's forum.

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing the SQL? Spring won't magically log SQL that gets sent to the database, you have to go through the appropriate channels.

For example, if you execute SQL by using `JdbcTemplate`, either directly or via `JdbcDaoSupport`, then yes, the SQL will be logged for some operations, but only those operations that involve direct SQL.

If you use Hibernate or prepared statements, then Spring never gets to see the SQL itself, and therefore cannot log it.

If you posted some sample code that demonstrated how you were executing your SQL, it would help a lot.

Comment: I'm using Spring's JdbcTemplate.  I'm actually using some copyrighted sample code (from Enterprise Spring Recicpes), so don't think I should post it.  I will try to hack out my own example though, that is my next step.