# Seeing the underlying SQL in the Spring JdbcTemplate?

Tags: sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am learning about the wonders of JdbcTemplate and NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. I like what I see, but is there any easy way to see the underlying SQL that it ends up executing? I'd like to see this for debug purposes (in order to for example debug the resulting SQL in an outside tool).

Comment: To clarify, I'd like to see the SQL with the '?' inside to make sure that whole process worked correctly.

Comment: Hi Artem,Did u achieve this in your code ?

Comment: If using Intellij Debugger, press double shift, enter this: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate#query(java.lang.String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource, org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<T>)

Comment: @JanacMeena that brings me to `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` class definition. Using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3.

Comment: Hey @MarcoLackovic, my comment is from 3 years ago, so it's likely that the spring framework has changed around a bit. I would recommend trying some of the other answers.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/jdbc/core.html) says they're logged at DEBUG level:

> *All SQL issued by this class is logged at the `DEBUG` level under the category corresponding to the fully qualified class name of the template instance (typically `JdbcTemplate`, but it may be different if you use a custom subclass of the `JdbcTemplate` class).*

In XML terms, you need to configure the logger something like:

```xml
<category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <priority value="debug" />
</category>
```

This subject was however discussed here a month ago and it seems not as easy to get to work as in Hibernate and/or it didn't return the expected information: [Spring JDBC is not logging SQL with log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792244/argh-cant-get-spring-to-log-sql). You could also use [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) instead which can also be [integrated in Spring Boot](https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator).

Comment: Use as name "org.springframework.jdbc", to also see the real SQL queries.

Comment: I used <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" level="trace" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileApp" />
  </Logger>

Comment: What if I want to see multiline SQL into single log statement?

Answer (score 51):

This works for me with org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar.
I could not find this anywhere in the Spring docs (maybe I'm just lazy) but I found (trial and error) that the TRACE level did the magic.

I'm using log4j-1.2.15 along with slf4j (1.6.4) and properties file to configure the log4j:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

This displays both the SQL statement and bound parameters like this:

```
Executing prepared SQL statement [select HEADLINE_TEXT, NEWS_DATE_TIME from MY_TABLE where PRODUCT_KEY = ? and NEWS_DATE_TIME between ? and ? order by NEWS_DATE_TIME]
Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [aaa], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [Thu Oct 11 08:00:00 CEST 2012], value class [java.util.Date], SQL type unknown
Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [Thu Oct 11 08:00:10 CEST 2012], value class [java.util.Date], SQL type unknown
```

Not sure about the SQL type unknown but I guess we can ignore it here

For just an SQL (i.e. if you're not interested in bound parameter values) `DEBUG` should be enough.

Comment: I think this may work with jdbc, but no jdbctemplate. Not working for me too

Comment: For me this is working with Spring 4.2.4 and `JdbcTemplate`

Comment: it also worked great with logback: <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="your-appender-ref" />
    </logger>

Comment: it doesn't show sql exceptions in the logs.

Answer (score 38):

I use this line for Spring Boot applications:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

This approach pretty universal and I usually use it for any other classes inside my application.

Comment: please let me know at the annotation leve.. i don't have any xml or property file..

Comment: 2020 is all about annotations  fortunately or unfortunately

Comment: I think there is no way to do this with annotations, only property file or logback.xml. I even can't imagine why this should be available at the annotation level

Answer (score 10):

Parameter values seem to be printed on TRACE level. This worked for me:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG, file
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE, file
```

Console output:

```
02:40:56,519 TRACE http-bio-8080-exec-13 core.StatementCreatorUtils:206 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [Tue May 31 14:00:00 CEST 2005], value class [java.util.Date], SQL type unknown
02:40:56,528 TRACE http-bio-8080-exec-13 core.StatementCreatorUtils:206 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [61], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type unknown
02:40:56,528 TRACE http-bio-8080-exec-13 core.StatementCreatorUtils:206 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [80], value class [java.lang.Integer], SQL type unknown
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me with log4j2 and xml parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/some_path/logs/</Property>
        <Property name="app-id">my_app</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/${app-id}.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/${app-id}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Result console and file log was:

```
JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [select a, b from c where id = ? ]
StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [my_id], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

Just copy/past

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in log4j.xml

```
<!--  enable query logging -->
<category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
</category>

<!-- enable query logging for SQL statement parameter value -->
<category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils">
    <priority value="TRACE" />
</category>
```

your logs looks like:

```
DEBUG JdbcTemplate:682 - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG JdbcTemplate:616 - Executing prepared SQL statement [your sql query]
TRACE StatementCreatorUtils:228 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [param], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do this without any xml or yml config , but as simple as only pure java code ,like below:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate");
logger.setLevel(Level.valueOf("DEBUG"));

// Or ,for more datasource details,you can retrieve another logger  like this 
// Logger logger2 = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.springframework.jdbc");
//logger2.setLevel(Level.valueOf("DEBUG"));
```

Enjoy it, guys,
see more from here https://www.bswen.com/2019/05/springboot-How-to-print-JPA-and-jdbcTemplate-SQL-logs.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you use ch.qos.logback add a logger:

```
  <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="trace"/>
```