# PreparedStatement Logging

Tags: log4j

I use log4j for the logging.
I could see the SQLs through Log4j like below.

Here's my java source which access data base with jdbcTemplate.

```
public QnaDTO selectBoard(int articleID) {
        String SQL = 
            "SELECT " +
            "   QA.ARTICLE_ID, " +
            "   QA.EMAIL, " +
            "   QA.TEL, " +
            "   QA.CATEGORY_ID, " +
            "   CG.CATEGORY_NAME, " +
            "   QA.SUBJECT, " +
            "   QA.CONTESTS, " +
            "   QA.WRITER_NAME, " +
            "   QA.WRITER_ID, " +
            "   QA.READCOUNT, " +
            "   QA.ANSWER, " +
            "   QA.FILE_NAME, " +
            "   QA.OPEN_FLG, " +
            "   QA.KTOPEN_FLG, " +
            "   TO_CHAR(QA.WRITE_DAY, 'YYYY.MM.DD') WRITE_DAY, " +
            "   QA.DISPOSAL_FLG " +
            "FROM QNA QA JOIN QNA_CATEGORY_GROUP CG " +
            "ON QA.CATEGORY_ID = CG.CATEGORY_ID " +
            "WHERE QA.ARTICLE_ID = ? ";

        QnaDTO qnaDTO = (QnaDTO) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                SQL,
                new Object[]{articleID}, 
                new RowMapper() {
                    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        QnaDTO qnaDTO = new QnaDTO();
                        qnaDTO.setArticleID(rs.getInt("ARTICLE_ID"));
                        qnaDTO.setCategoryID(rs.getInt("CATEGORY_ID"));
                        qnaDTO.setCategoryName(rs.getString("CATEGORY_NAME"));
                        qnaDTO.setEmail1(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
                        qnaDTO.setTel1(rs.getString("TEL"));
                        qnaDTO.setSubject(rs.getString("SUBJECT"));
                        qnaDTO.setContests(rs.getString("CONTESTS"));
                        qnaDTO.setName(rs.getString("WRITER_NAME"));
                        qnaDTO.setUserID(rs.getString("WRITER_ID"));
                        //
                        qnaDTO.setReadcount(rs.getString("READCOUNT"));
                        qnaDTO.setAnswer(rs.getString("ANSWER"));
                        qnaDTO.setFileName(rs.getString("FILE_NAME"));
                        qnaDTO.setOpenFlg(rs.getString("OPEN_FLG"));
                        qnaDTO.setKtOpenFlg(rs.getString("KTOPEN_FLG"));
                        //
                        qnaDTO.setWriteDay(rs.getString("WRITE_DAY"));
                        qnaDTO.setDisposalFlg(rs.getString("DISPOSAL_FLG"));
                        return qnaDTO;
                    }
                }
            );
            return qnaDTO;
    }
```

As you can see above.
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(...) is the method which really send Query And Get some result.

**Inside of jdbcTemplate.queryForObject, finally logger used**

```
public Object query(final String sql, final ResultSetExtractor rse)
    throws DataAccessException
{
    Assert.notNull(sql, "SQL must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(rse, "ResultSetExtractor must not be null");
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("Executing SQL query [" + sql + "]");
    class _cls1QueryStatementCallback
        implements StatementCallback, SqlProvider
    {

        public Object doInStatement(Statement stmt)
            throws SQLException
        {
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Object obj;
            try
            {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                ResultSet rsToUse = rs;
                if(nativeJdbcExtractor != null)
                    rsToUse = nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativeResultSet(rs);
                obj = rse.extractData(rsToUse);
            }
            finally
            {
                JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public String getSql()
        {
            return sql;
        }

        _cls1QueryStatementCallback()
        {
            super();
        }
    }

    return execute(new _cls1QueryStatementCallback());
}
```

But with above sources, I could only get the SQL with ?.
What I want is that my result doesn't have question mark **?**
It means filling ? with real data.

Is there any way to do this?
thanks

Comment: when the code has some filling the real data, then you should log that using toString() or any equivalent method.

Comment: yes, I think so..Difficult languages

Comment: shouldn't be that difficult, update this question with a few lines of the java codes between your select query and then I will take a look.

Comment: thanks Jasonw! I edited any question for your ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeon, sorry, was occupied with work. :-) Anyway, I have looked into your code and replicate here using spring 2.5. I've also google and I think you want to read [this](http://ramblingabout.wordpress.com/2007/01/03/logging-sql-queries-with-spring/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932208/seeing-the-underlying-sql-in-the-spring-jdbctemplate) further to understand.

From the official [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html),

> Finally, all of the SQL issued by this class is logged at the 'DEBUG'
>   level under the category corresponding to the fully qualified class
>   name of the template instance (typically JdbcTemplate, but it may be
>   different if a custom subclass of the JdbcTemplate class is being
>   used).

So you need to figure out how to enable logging with debug level.

Not sure exactly how you trace, but with my trace, I end up to below. So if you enable debug level, you should be able to see the output, maybe not **exactly** like `QA.ARTICLE_ID = 123;` but you should probably get the value printed in the next line something like in that [example](http://ramblingabout.wordpress.com/2007/01/03/logging-sql-queries-with-spring/). Anyway, I don't have the exact setup like in your environment but this I think should you give a clue.

```
public Object execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback action)
        throws DataAccessException {

    Assert.notNull(psc, "PreparedStatementCreator must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        String sql = getSql(psc);
        logger.debug("Executing prepared SQL statement" + (sql != null ? " [" + sql + "]" : ""));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to set DEBUG MODE on.

Comment: Depending on my research yesterday, there's no way to my extract SQL from PreparedStatement instance. Anyway, I am seeing the value filled SQL now. I could do this because I print them before they're sent to *execute* method or something similar method thanks to you. I appreciate your help!! from Korea.

Comment: this is simply source only to see log.

Comment: public Object query(String sql, Object[] args, ResultSetExtractor rse) throws DataAccessException {
  printFormattedSql(sql, args);
  return query(sql, new ArgPreparedStatementSetter(args), rse);
 }

Comment: public void printFormattedSql(String sql, Object[] args) {
  for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
   sql = sql.replaceFirst("\\?", String.valueOf(args[i]));
  }
  
  Formatter f = new BasicFormatterImpl();
  String formattedSql = f.format(sql);
  
  logger.debug(formattedSql+"\n\n");
 }

Comment: jeon, good job! I'm glad it works out fine in your sample code. Keep up the good work.