# How can I configure Spring to show the query performed by JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I am developing a batch using Spring. To perform the query I use **JdbcTemplate**.

In my specific case **JdbcTemplate** is provided to the DAO class extending the Spring **JdbcDaoSupport** class, so I have the following DAO:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class PucManagerColl extends JdbcDaoSupport {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PucManagerProd.class);

    public PucManagerColl() {
        System.out.println("Costruzione PucManager");
    }

    @Autowired
    public PucManagerColl(@Qualifier("dataSourcePUCColl") DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);

    }

    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................

        public void insertTirConsolidatoPolizza(TassoRendimentoInterno tri) {

        log.debug("PucManagerColl.insertTirConsolidatoPolizza()");

        String sql = "INSERT INTO TirConsolidatoPolizza "
                   + "("
                   + "Polizzaid, "
                   + "PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioGestione, "
                   + "PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioAnno, "
                   + "PercentualeRendimentoDaInizioTrimestre, "
                   + "ControvaloreFinaleBF, "
                   + "DataRiferimentoNav"
                   + ") "
                   + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


        this.getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,  
                  new Object[] { tri.getPolizzaID(),
                                 tri.getPercRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione(),
                                 tri.getPercRendimentoInizioAnno(),
                                 tri.getPercRendimentoInizioTrimestre(),
                                 tri.getControvaloreQuote(),
                                 tri.getDataRiferimentoNavPUC()});


        log.debug("TERMINATO: PucManagerColl.insertTirConsolidatoPolizza()");
    }
}
```

As you can see this class extends Spring class **JdbcDaoSupport** and the datasource is injected into the constructor.

The problem is that the **insertTirConsolidatoPolizza()** method can't insert the record into the **TirConsolidatoPolizza** table. I obtain no error and no excption. Why? Do you notice some problem in my query?

So I want debug the query genrated by **JdbcTemplate** and try to perform it manually into the database prompt but I can't see it.

Reading this post: [Seeing the underlying SQL in the Spring JdbcTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932208/seeing-the-underlying-sql-in-the-spring-jdbctemplate#)

and the official doumentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

it seems to me that I can configure **JdbcTemplate** to log the query in debug mode or something like it.

In the other post show this XML snippet to do it:

```
<category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <priority value="debug" />
</category>
```

but I don't know exactly where I hae to put it.

This is my **databaseConfiguration.xml** that contains the informations for the DB connection (I import this file into the main configuration file applicationContext.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="tjtJTransactionManager" />

    <!-- DB CONNECTIONS: -->
    <bean id="tjtJTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        scope="singleton">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePUC" />
    </bean>

    <!-- PROFILO DI PRODUZIONE -->
    <beans profile="PROD">

        <bean id="dataSourcePUC" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://XXX.myCompany.YYYY.it:1433/DB_1" />
            <property name="username" value="username" />
            <property name="password" value="pswd" />
        </bean>

    </beans>

    <!-- PROFILO DI COLLAUDO -->
    <beans profile="COLL">

        <bean id="dataSourcePUC" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://XXXX.MYCOMPANY.YYYY.it:1433/DB_2" />
            <property name="username" value="username" />
            <property name="password" value="pswd" />

        </bean>

    </beans>

</beans>
```

How can I configure the query logging to see the performed query in my stacktrace?

Comment: where your transaction is getting committed?

Comment: I think you should annotate `insertTirConsolidatoPolizza` with `@Transactional`.

Comment: You have to set package `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` to at least DEBUG mode. This is done in the logging configuration, whichever implementation you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I configure Spring to show the query performed by JdbcTemplate?

It depends on logging framework you use.
For example, for log4j you can place following lines in log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value ="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>

  <category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <priority value="debug" />
  </category>
</log4j:configuration>
```

You have to make sure log4j.xml is in the project class path.
See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for detailed configuration instructions.

PS: By the way, correct query should look like

```
getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,  
              tri.getPolizzaID(),
              tri.getPercRendimentoInizioSottoscrizione(),
              tri.getPercRendimentoInizioAnno(),
              tri.getPercRendimentoInizioTrimestre(),
              tri.getControvaloreQuote(),
              tri.getDataRiferimentoNavPUC());
```