# Show Sql in spring jdbc applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm writing a plain spring jdbc application using spring boot after a long time without using jpa or hibernate or any other ORM solution. I have need to print the **runtime** **SQL** for debugging purposes. I researched a little bit but could not find anything. I know in a jpa/hibernate application we can say following in ***application.properties***

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

But not sure what is the name name of property in spring jdbc applications. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a matter of a logger setting for `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`. [See log4j for example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932208/seeing-the-underlying-sql-in-the-spring-jdbctemplate)

Comment: I used the following config in logback xml file:
`<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="TRACE"/>`