# Why does Spring-data-jdbc not save my Car object?

Tags: java, insert, spring-data-jdbc

*I'm playing around with spring-data-jdbc and discovered a problem, with I can't solve using Google.*

No matter what I try to do, I just can't push a trivial object into the database (Bean1.java:25):
`carRepository.save(new Car(2L, "BMW", "5"));`

Both, without one and with a TransactionManager +`@Transactional` the database (apparently) does not commit the record.

*The code is based on a Postgres database, but you might also simply use a H2 below and get the same result.*

Here is the (minimalistic) source code:
https://github.com/bitmagier/spring-data-jdbc-sandbox/tree/stackoverflow-question

Can somebody tell me, why the car is not inserted into the database?

Comment: There is a closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52772648/66686

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not related to transactions not working.
Instead, it's about Spring Data JDBC considering your instance an existing instance that needs updating (instead of inserting).

You can verify this is the problem by [activating logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932208/seeing-the-underlying-sql-in-the-spring-jdbctemplate) for `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. You should see an `update` but no `insert`.

By default, Spring Data JDBC considers an entity as new when it has an id of an object type and a value of `null` or of a primitive type (e.g. `int` or `long`) and a value of `0`.
If your entity has an attribute with `@Version` annotation that attribute will be used to determine if the instance is a new one.

You have the following options in order to make it work:

1. Set the id to `null` and configure your database schema so that it will automatically create a new value on insert. After the save your entity instance will contain the generated value from the database.

   *Note: Spring Data JDBC will set the id even if it is final in your entity.*
2. Leave the id `null` and set it in a Before-Convert listener to the desired value.
3. Let your entity implement [`Persistable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html). This allows you to control when an entity is considered *new*. You'll probably need a listener as well so you can let the entity know it is not new any longer.
4. Beginning with version 1.1 of Spring Data JDBC you'll also be able to use a `JdbcAggregateTemplate` to do a direct insert, without inspecting the id, see `https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-282`. Of course, you can do that in a custom method of your repository, as is done in this example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/pull/441

Comment: I asked a similar question yesterday, and Jens was good enough to link my question to this one, and I confirmed this answer essentially made my question a duplicate. So I just wanted to say thanks to Jens. Thanks Jens!

Comment: is this only true for Aggregate Roots? I just noticed that I have a child class, which sets its PK in client code before persistence (it's using a UUID fyi), and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Short answer: yes, kind of. Long answer please ask a separate question.