# How to log SQL statements and parameters with Spring Data JDBC

Tags: logging, spring-data-jdbc

If you want to see what SQL statements Spring Data JDBC is executing, how would you do that?
Since it uses bind variables, I also want to see their values in the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC uses a `JdbcTemplate` to execute all SQL statements.
[So you really need to configure logging for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932208/seeing-the-underlying-sql-in-the-spring-jdbctemplate).

The statements itself are logged by the template itself with `DEBUG` level.
To see these you have to set the log level of `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` to `DEBUG`.

The arguments for the bind variables are logged by `org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils` on `TRACE` level.

How you configure those depends on your project setup.
You can use the configuration options of Log4J, Logback or whatever logging implementation you are using.
Or if you happen to use Spring Boot the following rows in the `application.properties` should do the trick.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
```

Or simply

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
```

If you don't mind possibly getting some extra output.

Comment: how to do this configuration with logback. I can only see the SQL generated but not errors inside sql. for e.g column not found