# How to get sql with replaced values using JdbcTemplate and BeanPropertySqlParameterSource?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm getting an error by executing jdbc.update(sql, params) and I would like to see the sql that is executing jdbc.update but with the final values instead :param that is in the sql before execution.

Is there any method of JdbcTemplate that allows to do that?

```
public boolean create(User user) {
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = 
        new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(user);

    String sql = "INSERT INTO t_user (username, password, email)"
        + " VALUES (:username, :password, :email)";

    return jdbc.update(sql, params) == 1;
}
```

I need to get sql that is going to execute jdbcTemplate, and it is something like

```
INSERT INTO t_user (username, password, email)
       VALUES ("name", "password", "joe@mail.com")
```

I need this to check if the sql is right, because I have too many parameters to do all that by hand.

Comment: not possible. if you are using sqlserver use MSSQL TRACE application

Comment: Try adding log4j. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1810851/2607501

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my code

```
String DELETE_BY_ID_QUERY = "delete from my_table where id = ?";
....
String id ="a123";

getJdbcTemplate().update(DELETE_BY_ID_QUERY, new Object[] { id });
```

**EDIT**: After reading your Edit to question

You can use the API

```
public int update(PreparedStatementCreator psc) throws DataAccessException
```

and then pass in an implementation of `PreparedStatementCreator` for e.g. (`SimplePreparedStatementCreator`) and print the sql when the PreparedStatement is created. I haven't tried this, but I think you should be able to get it.